# php mandatory field based on drop down list value

Tags: php

I have a form in PHP which has drop downlist and a textboxt which shows and hide bases on dropdown list value. I did the show and hide using javascript.

My question is I want to make the text box mandatory when it become visible and an error to appear if the user left the textbox empty.

I did the form validation using `preg_match` but how to do the conditional mandatory based on the dropdown list selected value?

**EDIT:**

here is my show/hide feild in js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
    if(name != 'High School')
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
}

function hidefield() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

and this is my php validation

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$|\p{Arabic}/u", $_POST["name"]) === 0)
    $errname = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';'
```

Comment: The idea is to first check the value of the dropdown, then, if it matches certain criteria, check the value of the textbox.  Show us your code - we'll help you nail it.

Comment: Do you want to do this with JavaScript (i.e on the browser without a server round-trip) or via the server (in PHP)? The latter is usually best if you intend to only do one of them, as JS does not always work.

Comment: @halfer I prefer to do it with php

Comment: @Aleks G here is my show/hide feild in js '<script type="text/javascript">
 
    function showfield(name){
    if(name != 'High School')document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    else document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
  }
 
  function hidefield() {
 document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
 }


</script>'and this is my php validation 'if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$|\p{Arabic}/u", $_POST["name"]) === 0) 
          $errname = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';'

Comment: What you're missing in your PHP is the check of the dropdown value.  In your HTML, you have a text field with name `name`, which you are checking, but you also have a `select` element - I don't know the name.  In your PHP when checking that the name is empty, first check what value the dropdown is set to.  So it would be something like `if($_POST['dropdown'] != 'highschool' && preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$|\p{Arabic}/u", $_POST["name"]) === 0)` in the conditional.

Comment: @AleksG - add your comment as an answer, and I reckon the OP will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing in your PHP is the check of the dropdown value. In your HTML, you have a text field with name *name*, which you are checking, but you also have a select element - I don't know the name. In your PHP when checking that the name is empty, first check what value the dropdown is set to. So it would be something like

```
if($_POST['dropdown'] != 'highschool' &&
   preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$|\p{Arabic}/u", $_POST["name"]) === 0)
{
    $errname = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to come up with a javascript client side scripting.

On submit call javascript function validate()

```
<form name="xxx" method="get" onsubmit="validate()">
```

In the javascript function validate(),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validate(){

     var schoolname=document.getElementById("schoolName");

     var yearofpassing=document.getElementById("yop");

     if(isEmpty(schoolname)){

        alert("schoolname is mandatory");

        document.getElementById("schoolname").value="Please Enter School Name";

        document.getElementById("schoolname").focus();

        return false;
        } // Similarly Give Validation for Year of Passing field
```

Also if you want specific patterns in the text field, use Javascript match() function [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) for reference & Usage

```
     return true;
     }

</script>
```

Body Part

```
<body>
<form name="input" action="processinput.php" method="get">
<div id="div1">
   School Name :<input type="text" id="schoolname"> <br>
   Year of Passing : <input type="text" id="yop"><br>
</div>
<div id="div2">
   CODE
<div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd say JS is actually not better - JS can be disabled client-side, or might not be supported on a client device. If you don't also have server-side validation, you might be allowing invalid (or malicious) input into your database.

Comment: Thx to all of u ,,, appreciate ur help @Anoop Pere I did it with php